# Properties about Julia sets

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

I read books *The Beauty of Fractals --- Images of complex dynamical systems*, in one chapter it shows properties of [Julia Set](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Julia_set) as follows (we just consider rational functions on Riemann Surface where Julia set is denoted $J_R$),

- $ J_R \neq \emptyset$ and contains more than countably many points.
- The Julia sets are completely invariant, which means $R(J_R)=R^{-1}(J_R)=J_R$.
- The Julia sets of $R$ and $R^k$, $k= 1,2, \cdots ,$ are identical, where $R^k$ is $k$ times iterations of rational function $R$.
- For any $x\in J_R$, the inverse orbit $Or^-(x)$ is dense in $J_R$, where $Or^-(x_0)=\{x\in\overline {\mathbb C}:R^k(x)=x_0, k=0,1,2\cdots\}$.

Now I have a proof from some paper of how to prove $J_R$ is not an empty set in the point of topological degree, I cannot understand it. I want some more accessible ways to prove it, better not using topological degree. I have no idea how to start to show that $J_R$ contains more than countably many points, should I start from proving it is infinite and not countable?

$J_R$ is left invariant about the function $R$, it is easy to understand, but how about $R^{-1}(J_R)=J_R$?

Third property seems easy to understand for me.

Last one, I do not know how to start, either, should I use definition of $Dense$?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: These are not easy questions; you should probably consult a text book, like [Devaney's advanced undergraduate text](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Chaotic-Dynamical-Systems-2nd/dp/0813340853) or [Beardon's graduate text](https://www.amazon.com/Iteration-Rational-Functions-Dynamical-Mathematics/dp/0387951512).

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Thanks for your suggestion,I will read the book.